# Ad hoc query support in NOSQL

Tags: cassandra, nosql

We can store as much duplicate data as we need in the NOSQL dbs. Data must be saved in the same pattern in which we want to access out of it. There might be cases where we don't the access pattern in which we might need to access the data e.g. Ad hoc queries.

My company works on the financial domain where ad hoc queries are used most often. Right now we use the SQL server so stored procedure are used to perform the ad hoc data calculations.

Here i mean the query which can't be predicted in advance by ad hoc query.

How we could model the this query behavior in NOSQL. Right now we are evaluating Cassandra but we are open to switch to other NOSQL databases

Any lead ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for full text search then solr could be a good fit: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: I could use the Apache spark on top of the cassandra but could we better model storage pattern in order to get data fast

Comment: I agree with using a lucene based search tool. Spark is better Hadoop, it's batch analytics - not search. I'll save you a lot of pain by telling you to avoid Spark for search use cases.